# Как подключить bootstrap для всех .html файлов в java spring приложении?

Tags: html, bootstrap, java-ee, thymeleaf

У меня есть java spring boot сайт, в нём я использую thymeleaf; Структура файлов такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете я посмотрел, как вообще подключается Bootstrap и нашёл для себя удобным способ через  , это вроде называется Bootstrap CDN. Как мне применить подключение bootstrap cdn для всех html файлов ?

Думал попробовать с index.html и туда запихать эти   и как-то что-то с чем-то протянуть, но я себе это представить не могу и как проверить, подключился ли bootstrap или нет - не знаю.

Хотелось бы узнать какой-нибудь способ подключения bootstrap без костылей, чтобы было всё как-то автоматизировано что-ли и при создании нового .html, не приходилось постоянно прописывать  , а так-же чтобы не возникало расхождение версий при обновлении

Answer (score -1):

А в чем проблема прописать CDN в каждом документе, там всего лишь  и  для css и js ?

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

А проверку можешь сделать с помощью:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>`

Синяя кнопка есть - работает.

https://bootstrap5.ru/docs/components/buttons

Comment: А если проект большой и .html файлов много? А если нужно обновить bootstrap во всех этих html файлах? По одному файлу перебирать? Это же лютые костыли, а я спрашиваю про человеческие способы